# DPDK application stalls after receiving more than 8000 rte_mbuff

Tags: dpdk

Hello members of stackoverflow

I am developing a project with DPDK but have encountered a silly issue, that is not obvious to me. 
I want to find out the right approach to tackle my current problem.

I am sending and receiving 4kb rte_mbuf between remote and local node, 
that alone works fine, 
however when I combine the implementation with 3rd party library, the DPDK stops receiving the data after approximately receiving 8000 packets.

I have debugged all the possible program side and to my astonishment. there is no error found and all the packets that are within 8000 are received correctly.

I have  no idea the approach to find out the problem of this situation. but the situation that I have mentioned can be replicated. It always stops at approximately 8000 packets received. 
and there are absolutely no bugs found in dpdk (user interface). The only problem is the rte_rx_queue stops returning the packets after 8000 packets.

Would there be a good approach to identify the problem of this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would there be a good approach to identify the problem of this case?

The best approach would be to start with the stats. Have a look at [rte_eth_stats_get()](http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#adec226574c53ae413252c9b15f6f4bab)

We need to check if any counter is increasing after the DPDK app has stopped. I bet the [rx_nombuf counter](http://doc.dpdk.org/api/structrte__eth__stats.html#a8afc3f87397701e58b218d9dad03be8c) is still increasing, which might mean your mempool has exhausted.

If we pass the mbuf to an external lib, we have to make sure that each mbuf is freed after return from the lib.